# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry cannot be cast to com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieEntry

Tags: java, android

Accepting data from database and displaying it on Table Layout and using that data creating a piechart with MpAndroidChart  Library but getting the error as stated above

I am transfering arraylist from one activity to other using putextra and getSerializableExtra while accepting "**the error is shown as above**"

I am sharing my code please help

yValue is my arraylist where data is stored

transfering it to mylist using intent but this is generating error

My code:-

```
public class DisplayDate extends MainActivity{


    public ArrayList<PieEntry> yValues = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_date);

        doInBackground();

        pieChart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent pieIntent = new Intent(DisplayDate.this,DisplayPiechart.class);
                pieIntent.putExtra("Pie Values",yValues);
                startActivity(pieIntent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void doInBackground()
    {
        ConnectionHelper connectString = new ConnectionHelper();
        connect = connectString.connectionClass();

        Log.w("Android","Connecting....");

        if (connect == null)
        {
            Log.w("Android","Connection Failed");
            ConnectionResult = "Check Your Internet Connection";
        }
        else
        {
            Log.w("Android","Connected");
            String query = "Select No_,Name,Date,[Net Amount],[Gross Amount] from [CRONUS LS 1010 W1 Demo$Store] as str,[CRONUS LS 1010 W1 Demo$Transaction Header] as trans where str.[No_] = trans.[Store No_] and trans.[Date] between '"+Actual_Start+"' and '"+Actual_End+"' ";
            try
            {
                Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

                Log.w("Android","database Connected");

                while (rs.next()) {

                    TR = new TableRow(this);

                    TV1.setText(rs.getString("No_"));
                    TV2.setText(rs.getString("Name"));
                    TV4.setText(rs.getString("Date"));
                    TV5.setText(rs.getString("Net Amount"));
                    TV3.setText(rs.getString("Gross Amount"));

                    TL.addView(TR);

                    c = TV3.getText().toString();
                    a = Float.parseFloat(c);
                    d = TV1.getText().toString();

                    yValues.add(new PieEntry(a,d));
                }

                ConnectionResult = "Successful";
                isSuccess = true;
                connect.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

class DisplayPiechart extends DisplayDate{

    com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart pieChart;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_piechart);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        ArrayList<PieEntry> myList = (ArrayList<PieEntry>) i.getSerializableExtra("Pie Values");


        //Error at below line    
           PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(myList, "Stores");


        dataSet.setSliceSpace(2f);
        dataSet.setSelectionShift(6f);
        dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS);

        PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
        data.setValueTextSize(10f);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        pieChart.setData(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: **TL;DR** for your code. Please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Could you please add the stacktrace. It would help to see where the error occours. Your general problemis that you try to cast from Entry to PiEntry and not from PiEntry to Entry.

Comment: Error occur at                PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(myList, "Stores");

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but was running into the same issue. I'm new at this so take it with a grain of salt. There is probably a better way of solving it but posting it in case it helps someone.

I solved it by creating an ArrayList in the receiving activity as such:

```
ArrayList<Entry> receivedData;
receivedData = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then stored the data passed from the first activity into this ArrayList:

```
receivedData = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("data");

// Get size of ArrayList
int size = receivedData.size();

// Getting individual X and Y values from each ArrayList element    
for(int k = 0; k < size; k++){

     // Adding X and Y values as entries in a different
     // ArrayList barEntriesArrayList
     addDataPointsToGraph((int) receivedData.get(k).getX(), receivedData.get(k).getY());
}
```

And here is that Method:

```
private void addDataPointsToGraph(int x, float y){
    barEntriesArrayList.add(new BarEntry(x, y));
}
```

I then supplied this ArrayList barEntriesArrayList to the dataSet

```
// creating a new bar data set.
barDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(barEntriesArrayList, getResources().getString(R.string.valuePerDay));
```

I was using these two tutorials as a guide when generating my graph

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-barchart-in-android/

https://learntodroid.com/how-to-display-a-bar-chart-in-your-android-app/